# Какой Layot больше подходит?

Tags: android-view, android

Здравствуйте!

Помогите правильно подобрать разметку для отображения двух картинок так, чтобы получилось отображение

- при портретной ориентации: первая сверху, вторая снизу;
- при горизонтальной ориентации: первая слева, вторая справа;
  картинки должны прилипать друг к другу по центру.
  Какой  Layot и какое соотношение fill_ parent, match_ parent, wrap_content выбрать для каждого ImageView ?

Вроде простой вопрос, но заблудился в трёх соснах.

Код разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/fon"
tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/aboutImageOne"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:contentDescription="@string/about_image" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/aboutImageTwo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:contentDescription="@string/about_image" />

</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что вам мешает создать 2 разных `layout` для портретного и пейзажного режима? Не зря же гугл придумал папки ресурсов `layout-land`, `layout-port`.  
Соотношение `fill_ parent`, `match_ parent`, `wrap_content` выбирайте исходя из того, в каком масштабе отображать картинки(занять макс. площадь, растянуть, оригинальный размер...).  
А что бы они по центру прилипали друг к другу достаточно выбрать `linear layout`, и выставить ему `gravity` в `center`.

Comment: Да всё правильно! Это я вчера протупил. Переработал. Каюсь.
Вертикал. Горизонтал. Плюс каждую картинку в свой лайаут и там её отцентровать.
Просто в манифесте я для каждого активити установил запрет на её пересоздание - вот отсюда вся чушь и шла.
Спасибо!